# How to submit form field values with a link?

Tags: javascript, coldfusion, radio-button, cfml

How can I submit the values of the textbox and radio button with "testLink1" in the following code:

```
<cfform name="frmEdit" method="POST" >
   <INPUT type="text" name="txtName" value ="" >
   <INPUT type="radio" name="typeA" value ="exempt" checked> Exempt
   <INPUT type="radio" name="typeA" value ="non_exempt"> Non-exempt
   <a href="test1.cfm">testLink1</a>
</cfform>
```

I have my own reason to use `<a>` tag instead of a submit button.

Comment: Why don't you just use a submit button?

Comment: _"I have my own reason to use <a> tag instead of submit"_ - it's almost certainly an invalid reason. You need JavaScript to make a link submit a form, and JS can also make a submit button do anything the link can, so why not say what you're actually trying to achieve here?

Comment: +1 on your comment @PeterBoughton, my thoughts exactly.  I went ahead and provided a simple answer as I am assuming that the OP just wants to know how to submit a form via a link/JavaScript.

Comment: On a side note, use `<label>`s especially with check boxes and radio buttons.

Answer (score 5):

In order to submit the form via a link you will need to use JavaScript. I have rewritten your code below:

```
<form name="frmEdit" action="test1.cfm" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="txtName" value="" >
    <input type="radio" name="typeA" value="exempt" checked="checked"> Exempt
    <input type="radio" name="typeA" value="non_exempt"> Non-exempt
    <a href="javascript:document.frmEdit.submit();">testLink1</a>
</form>
```

Or as Travis suggested below, change the `<a>` tag like so:

```
    <a href="#" onClick="document.frmEdit.submit(); return false;">testLink1</a>
```

This should work for your simple example.  All of the fields will be available to you in the `FORM` scope in ColdFusion.

There is also no reason to use `cfform` if you are not using any of it's functionality (which your example is not).

Comment: it would probably be better to do `onClick="document.frmEdit.submit(); return false;"` than to do it in the href

Comment: I saw that, I had to update my comment to match your post. I had mismatched quotes.